# Switching cell background color of a table created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, cell, background-color

I have a problem:
I need a table 7x48 cells, those cells have a background color (grey) which have to be switchable when clicked (green) and then switchable again with another click.
I created the table with the following js function:

```
function createGrid(){
// get the reference for the body
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    var green="#33CC66";
    var grey="#DEDEDE";

    // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
    var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    tbl.id="timegrid";
    tbl.style.backgroundColor=grey;
    // creating all cells
    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        // creates a table row
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
            // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
            // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
            // the end of the table row
            var cell = document.createElement("td");

            cell.onmousedown=function(){
                if(this.style.backgroundColor!=grey)
                this.style.backgroundColor=grey;
                else this.style.backgroundColor=green;                  

            };
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        // add the row to the end of the table body
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }

    // put the <tbody> in the <table>
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    // appends <table> into <div id="grid">
    grid.appendChild(tbl);
    tbl.setAttribute("cellPadding", "7");
    tbl.setAttribute("cellSpacing", "0");
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "1");}
```

The problem is: it works the first time (from grey the cell switches to green) but I can't turn back to the original color the second time I click on the same cell.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the browser doesn't keep the same value that you set.

For example, if you do

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#33cc66'
console.log(document.body.style.backgroundColor);
```

You get `rgb(51, 204, 102)` returned.  (And let it be known that StackOverflow is *hideous* with a green background.)

This value is the [functional notation for colour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value#section_7).

You probably need to store the value that you've set it to, because browsers are inconsistent in how they report the current colour value.

```
cell.onmousedown=function(){
    if(background !== grey) {
        this.style.backgroundColor=grey;
        background = grey;
    } else {
        this.style.backgroundColor=green;      
        background = green;            
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i just solved using classnames instead of declaring the cell's style in js: if(this.className=="greenCell") this.className="greyCell";
else this.className="greenCell";